# Type hints with module imported inside class scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have a class function that I only want to define if a certain module (`X`), defined as an installation "extra" is available.

```
class ABC:
    try:
        from X import y

        def to_y(self) -> ???:
            return self.y(self)

    except ImportError:
        pass
```

The problem here is that `y` is now tied to the scope of the class rather than the global scoping that type hints seem to need.

How do I get around this?

Obviously I could take all this outside the class scope and monkey patch in the `to_y` method. Or I could make a global variable which is `None` when `X` is not available and use that.

I'm curious if there's a better, more obvious way to achieve this.